# How to calculate more accurate distance between beacon and android device?

Tags: android, ibeacon, eddystone, indoor-positioning-system

I have tried to calculate distance from beacon to android device using RSSI and TxPower but fluctuation is very high. So how to get more stable distance ? I have tried with code snippet given below :

```
  public  double calculateAccuracy(int txPower, double rssi) {
        if (rssi == 0) {
            return -1.0;
        }
        double ratio = rssi * 1.0 / txPower;
        if (ratio < 1.0) {
            return Math.pow(ratio, 10);
        } else {
            double accuracy = (0.89976) * Math.pow(ratio, 7.7095) + 0.111;
            return accuracy;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this question, as rssi does fluctuate greatly, especially at larger distances.  This is exacerbated by  built-in channel switching on Bluetooth.  Each channel returns a different average RSSI.

The best you can do is average as many rssi measurements as possible over as long of a period as is reasonable for your use case.  You can use a simple arithmetic mean, or more sophisticated statistical filters, but the difference between then is not dramatic.

It is also useful to set your beacon's advertising rate as high as possible to get more statistical samples, and set the transmitter strength to be as high as possible as a larger signal to noise ratio will give you less variance in rssi.